# JScript encrypt & decrypt string using custom key

Tags: encryption, jscript

I'm trying to encrypt and then decrypt string using Rijndael with custom key.

```vb
Dim obj,arr,i,r,str,enc,utf
dim bytes,bytesd,s,sc,sd
set obj=WScript.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged")
Set utf = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
s="This is a private message"
bytes=utf.GetBytes_4(s)
obj.GenerateKey()
obj.GenerateIV()
set enc=obj.CreateEncryptor()
set dec=obj.CreateDecryptor()

bytec=enc.TransformFinalBlock((bytes),0,lenb(bytes))
sc=utf.GetString((bytec))
msgbox sc

byted=dec.TransformFinalBlock((bytec),0,lenb(bytec))
sd=utf.GetString((byted))
msgbox sd
```

I rewrote this vbscirpt code, which works perfectly into jscript.

But in my jscript solution, I'm getting an error: "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." The error is thrown during decryption at line `var result = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, string.length);`.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

```js
function CRYPTO(key) {

    this.Rijndael = WScript.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged");
    this.Unicode = WScript.CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding");

    var MD5 = WScript.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider");
    MD5.Initialize();

    var bytes = MD5.ComputeHash_2(this.Unicode.GetBytes_4(key));
    this.Rijndael.Key = bytes; this.Rijndael.IV = bytes;

}
CRYPTO.prototype.encrypt = function(string) {

    var bytes = this.Unicode.GetBytes_4(string);
    var encryptor = this.Rijndael.CreateEncryptor();

    var result = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, string.length);

    return this.Unicode.GetString(result);

}
CRYPTO.prototype.decrypt = function(string) {

    var bytes = this.Unicode.GetBytes_4(string);
    var decryptor = this.Rijndael.CreateDecryptor();

    var result = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, string.length);

    return this.Unicode.GetString(result);

}

var crypto = new CRYPTO(getMotherboardSerialNumber());

var before = "Hello World!";
WScript.Echo(before);

var after = crypto.encrypt(before);
WScript.Echo(after);

var back = crypto.decrypt(after);
WScript.Echo(back);

function getMotherboardSerialNumber() {
    var WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2");
    var items = new Enumerator(WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BaseBoard"));
    return items.item().SerialNumber;
}
```

Thanks in advance, sorry for my english.

Comment: Why do you need non-standard Rijndael Managed? It was implemented before the Rijndael becomes the AES standard with some differences.

Comment: Because it works for me, I don't know how to use the base class Rijndael. When I try to locate the class like this it fails `var standard = WScript.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, these aren't the same code. Your vbscript `enc` method correctly returns bytes, which you convert to a string only for display. (That's not particularly helpful, but it doesn't hurt anything.)

Your jscript `encrypt` tries to convert random bytes into a UTF-8 string. That's going to fail most of the time. The vast majority of things that will be returned by Rijndael are not valid UTF-8 sequences.

Get rid of the string encodings, and this will more likely work.

Note that your vbscript `asc` is actually a UTF-8 encoder, and `utf` is an ASCII encoder, which is probably a mistake. Also, your jscript does not create an IV, and insecurely generates its key. Both of these significantly reduce the security of this encryption. There should be a random IV for each encryption, as you have in the vbscript, and if you're going to use something like a serial number as the password, you need to pass it through a KDF such as PBKDF2, not a single MD5 hash. See [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes) for the correct tools.

Comment: Is there any way I can convert Rijndael sequences into strings, for example when I need them to be written into utf8 encoded file? Also how am I supposed to use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, I don't think that's possible in jscript/vbscript. I tried to locate the class like this `var test = WScript.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes");`, but unsuccessfully. Thank you for tips and time anyway.

Comment: You will need an encoding that can take an arbitrary set of bytes. The most popular is Base64. Hex-encoding is also popular. You may want to explore https://github.com/as08/ClassicASP.PasswordHashing I'm not familiar enough with vbscript security libraries to give good advise there; but what you want is a KDF (PBKDF2, scrypt), not a simple cryptographic hash (MD5, SHA).